# How can locator() be used with graphics devices?

Tags: r, graph

How can `locator()` be used when writing plots to a file?

```
pdf(file = 'foo.pdf')

  plot(i)
  x <- locator()
  text(x)


dev.off()
```

> Error in text.default(x) : zero-length 'labels' specified

Calls to `png()`, `bmp()`, etc, yield the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity:

The function `recordPlot()` serves reasonably well:

```
plot(i)
x <- locator(1)
text(x)
p1 <- recordPlot()


png(file = 'foo.pdf')
p1
dev.off()
```